# Dropzone.js: awaiting `processQueue` method

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, dropzone.js

I have used `Dropzone.js` in a progressive data submission form. To clarify the scenario, the user inputs personal data first, then upon clicking `next`, the `dropzone` form appears where user upload files.

I have disabled the `autoProcessQueue` in order to wait for the user to finish attaching all required files, and then I add additional parameters as well as authorization token. At this point, when the user clicks `next`, I call the `processQueue()` method and this results in immediate navigation to the next form while attached files are being uploaded in the meanwhile in the background. The problem is that, I need to wait for the files to be uploaded first before navigating to the next page. For example:

```
var dropZone = new Dropzone ('[vu-dropzone]', {
    ...
    autoProcessQueue = false,
    params: {
        purpose: 'Registration',
        level: 'A'
    },
    headers: {Authorization: this.$store.getters['user/getToken']}
}); 

//submission method 
// what I'm actually doing
submit(){
  this.dropZone.processQueue();
  // go to next route/form
}
```

> ```
> //what I'm after 
> async submit(){
>     await this.dropZone.processQueue();
>      // go to next route/form
> }
> ```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to wait for dropzone to upload all the images before moving to your next screen, you probably should use dropzone's own [`success`](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#event-success) or [`successmultiple`](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#event-successmultiple) events.

```
var dropZone = new Dropzone ('[vu-dropzone]', {
    // ...
    autoProcessQueue = false,
    params: {
        purpose: 'Registration',
        level: 'A'
    },
    headers: {Authorization: this.$store.getters['user/getToken']},
    uploadMultiple: true,
    maxFiles: 10,
    parallelUploads: 10,
    init: function() {
        this.on('successmultiple', function(file, response) {
            // Here you can go to next form/route
        }
    }
});
```

My recommendation is that you set `maxFiles` and `parallelUploads` to the same value, the maximum number of files you want to allow, this way when you call `processQueue()` all the files will be uploaded in one request.